# Change regular expression and error message based on another property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In the following partial class I have a property, `Amount` with a `RegularExpression` attribute. This works as it should--it limits the value in the field to 2 decimal places. However, the `Amount` field is used in multiple places and the number of decimal places varies depending on where it is used. A `CategoryId` determines the amount of decimal places to be displayed. Is there a way to change the decimal place limitation and the `ErrorMessage` based on another property in the class, `CategoryId`.

Here is the partial class:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CS_Parameter_Statewide_AllGrades_ScenarioMetaData))]
public partial class CS_Parameter_Statewide_AllGrades_Scenario
{   
    public int Category { get; set; }

    public class CS_Parameter_Statewide_AllGrades_ScenarioMetaData
    {
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$", ErrorMessage = "Price can't have more than 2 decimal places")]
        public double Amount { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Here is the loop in the View that displays the `Amount` values. If you look you can see that the display format will vary by using a `Format` method. The `Format` method returns a string which determines the format in the 'TextBoxFor()` overload.

```
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AllGradesParamList.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Model.CategoryList.Where(x => x.Id == Model.AllGradesParamList[i].CategoryId).Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault()
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.AllGradesParamList[i].CategoryId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.AllGradesParamList[i].Amount, Model.Format(Model.AllGradesParamList[i].Amount, Model.AllGradesParamList[i].CategoryId))
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.AllGradesParamList[i].Amount)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

I'm not sure if I need to write a custom attribute or not. But if I do could someone provide a simple but full example that will work as I described above.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just allow it to have as many decimals as possible, and add a method to ouput it with x decimals?

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to limit the input from the user

Answer (score 0):

There are several options; Like you suggest, it would be possible to write your own `ValidationAttribute`, maybe derive from the `RegularExpressionAttribute` class and whatnot. It may be a viable option to implement the `IValidatableObject` interface for more complex validation. Here's a quick example:

```
public class Awesome : IValidatableObject {

    [Required]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    public String Whatever { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
        // Perform validation checks...
        // If 'valid' return <null>,
        // and if not, populate the ValidationResult list and return that.
        // The validationContext.ObjectInstance contains what you need, if you
        // cast it properly (see my next example).
    }

}
```

If you don't care if the solution is not "all that", you could simply use a `CustomValidationAttribute`, like so:

```
public class Awesome {

    [Required]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    [CustomValidation(typeof(MyValidator), "ValidateThis")]
    public String Whatever { get; set; }

}
```

In your `MyValidator`, you can access the `Id` property like this:

```
public class MyValidator {

    public static ValidationResult ValidateThis(String value, ValidationContext context) {
        var awesome = context.ObjectInstance as Awesome;
        if(awesome == null)
            throw new InstanceNotFoundException(
                "This validator only works with an Awesome instance.");

        var id = awesome.Id;

        // Do your thing here, like run a dynamic regular expression match
        // based on the value of 'id'.

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

To me, this code is not perfect - I don't like how it assumes that the `ObjectInstance` is a particular type (maybe `context.ObjectInstance as IAwesome` is a little bit better), so I probably shouldn't suggest using it, but there it is.

On a side note, don't forget to check out `IClientValidatable` or something for adding client side validation for your custom validation solution. You're likely, I suppose, to want to implement this too sooner or later if you make your own `ValidationAttribute`.

Comment: Actually the IClientValidatable part is the part I'm having the hardest time with. Could you include it in your answer?

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at something like [Enabling Client Side Validation on Custom Data Annotations With IClientValidatable in MVC](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/enabling-client-side-validation-on-custom-data-annotations-w/). If you get into trouble, post a new question regarding that particular problem and the solutions you've tried ;)